# Determine the speed of the sailor in still water and the speed of the current.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A sailor goes $8$ $km$ downstream in $40$ minutes and returns in $1$ hour.
 **Question:** Determine the speed of the sailor in still water and the speed of the current.

Let the speed of the boat be $x$ $km/h$ and the speed of the current be $y$ $km/h$.
$\therefore$ Speed downstream $=(x+y)$ $km/h$
Speed upstream $=(x-y)$ $km/h$

I am unable to carry on further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since, $$speed = \frac{distance}{time}$$
$$x+y = \frac{8km}{4/6hr}$$
and $$x-y = \frac{8km}{1hr}$$
then solve both the equations.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

I suppose uniform motion, so you have $v=s/t$. And , using $v_1=x+y$ and $v_2=x-y$ you have a system of two linear equations. Can you write and solve this system?

Answer (score 0):

If the boat goes downstream $8$km in $40$minutes, then that means in $1$ hour, the boat would travel $12$km, by solving $8/40 = z/60$. So the speed of the boat downstream is $12$ km/h

Given in the question, we know that upstream, the speed of the boat is $8$ km/h.

Now using your equations, and plugging in these values, we have

$12 = x+y$  and

$8 = x-y$

Adding these equations together gives

$20 = 2x$, solving for $x$ gives $x = 10$. Plugging $x$ back in gives $12 = 10+y$ therefore $y =2$.